# ObjectMapper inconsistently mapping BigDecimal

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

I am using a custom serializer/deserializer for BigDecimals in JSON in my Spring Boot application. All float/double values are mapped as BigDecimals and the serializer/deserializer ensures that the scale of the BigDecimal is at least 2.

As an example I have the following in my unit test to create the ObjectMapper

```
private ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer customizer =
    jacksonObjectMapperBuilder -> {
        jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.featuresToEnable(DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS);
        jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.serializerByType(BigDecimal.class, new BigDecimalSerializer(BigDecimal.class));
        jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.deserializerByType(BigDecimal.class, new BigDecimalDeserializer());
    };

    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json();
    customizer.customize(builder);

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = builder.build();
    objectMapper.setNodeFactory(JsonNodeFactory.withExactBigDecimals(true));
    return objectMapper;
}
```

I then have the following unit test:

```
@Test
public void testCustomOM() {
    ObjectMapper om = getObjectMapper();
    ObjectNode rootNode = om.createObjectNode();
    rootNode.put("balance", new BigDecimal(37D));
    BigDecimal fromBigDecimal = om.convertValue(rootNode.get("balance"), BigDecimal.class);
    Map map = om.convertValue(rootNode, Map.class);
    BigDecimal fromMap = (BigDecimal) map.get("balance");
    assertEquals(2, fromBigDecimal.scale()); // Success
    assertEquals(2, fromMap.scale()); // Assert fails 
}
```

The BigDecimal serializer

```
public class BigDecimalSerializer extends StdSerializer<BigDecimal> {

    public BigDecimalSerializer(Class<BigDecimal> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(BigDecimal bigDecimal, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        generator.writeNumber(setScale(bigDecimal));
    }

    private BigDecimal setScale(BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
        if (bigDecimal.scale() < 2) {
            return bigDecimal.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
        }
        return bigDecimal;
    }
}
```

And BigDecimalDeserializer

```
public class BigDecimalDeserializer extends NumberDeserializers.BigDecimalDeserializer {

    @Override
    public BigDecimal deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        return setScale(super.deserialize(parser, context));
    }

    private BigDecimal setScale(BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
        if (bigDecimal.scale() < 2) {
            return bigDecimal.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
        }
        return bigDecimal;
    }
}
```

When I run the test, the BigDecimal I get from converting the JsonNode has a scale of two but the one I get from the Map is 0. So it seems that it is not using the BigDecimalDeserializer I have defined when converting to a Map.

Is there a way I can get the Jackson to consistently use this deserializer?